# Kubernetes Plugin on Jenkins: glusterfs mount for maven cache

Tags: maven, jenkins, kubernetes

I have setup a glusterFS cluster outside of kubernetes.
I added the glusterfs endpoint into kubernetes

I've tested the endpoint inside kubernetes with great success.

Now, how do I tell the plugin to mount the glusterfs ($HOME/.m2) on the maven image I have configured in the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Persistent Volume and Persistent Volume Claim, then mount PVC into the container within a pod.